# Need to split a high speed ADSL line for several departments

Tags: dhcp, vlan, qos, adsl

I'll try to keep it simple!

We have a new and very fast ADSL line coming in to our office which needs to be split between 4 different departments.
Each department will have a certain bandwidth available to them and we want them to have a separate IP range each, (IE 192.168.1.x, 192.168.2.x etc.). DHCP is required.

Is there an easy and cost effective way to achieve this? I'm not greatly knowledgeable in QoS or VLans, but am willing to learn.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide us more information, what router you use and what switch model you have

Comment: The most important thing for you to understand is that you have one pipe, and the other end decides what it puts on that pipe. If you're trying to divide the *inbound* bandwidth, you are trying to indirectly control what the other end of that pipe puts on the pipe. Simple QoS won't help with that.

Comment: The supplied router is a basic model that cannot manage what we require.

Comment: Then you need a more decent router. If you have a spare computer then my  recommendation is pfSense.